# How to use FIND_IN_SET or LOCATE or Having to get a count

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table which have multiple numeric value against a id. like for id = 200 values in table are value_id =(337,22,878,4,10,99) and for id=201 values are value_id=(337,22,878,99).

I used group_concat function to get all values against an id.

Now I want to have a total count of ids which do not contain value as 4.

For that i tried many thing like

1. COUNT( if(FIND_IN_SET(4, GROUP_CONCAT(value_id) )>0,1,NULL))
2. COUNT( if(LOCATE(4, GROUP_CONCAT(value_id) )>0,0,1))
3. GROUP_CONCAT(value_id) AS all_data,COUNT( if(LOCATE(4, all_data
   )>0,0,1))
4. COUNT( if(GROUP_CONCAT(alloc.table_id) = 4, 0, 1))
5. i tried using having also (i dont want to use it because of
   performance issue in Stored procedure)

Result : i am always getting Error Code: 1111. Invalid use of group function

```
select manager_profile_id,group_concat(value_id) as all_data
from managers  
where manager_profile_id =487 and team_id=2 
GROUP BY manager_profile_id HAVING all_data !=4 ;
```

Comment: Really comma separated values? databases aren't designed for comma separated values... i advice you the normalize the table  them you can count much eazier.

Comment: You want a total count of ids. Which id? manager_profile_id or team_id? I assume the not contained value is in value_id.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do:

```
select manager_profile_id, group_concat(value_id) as all_data
from managers  
where manager_profile_id = 487 and team_id = 2 
group by manager_profile_id
having sum( value_id = 4 ) = 0;
```

Comment: No Gordon, i do not want to sum them i just want to check if in all_data one of the numeric value is present (suppose 4 is present in one of the id group concat than that id should be excluded from my count )

Comment: @ami: This is what Gordon is doing: he is excluding all managers that have a value_id 4. How is Gordon's result different from what you want? `sum( value_id = 4 )` simply counts records with `value_id = 4` per group. This is due to MySQL's treating of true = 1, false = 0.

Comment: Yes i got the point now , sorry just started with DB things so not so good at it as of now. the solution works thanks a lot to both of you

Answer (score 0):

in you question is not clear if your id (eg:200) is a new column of or is manager_profile_id  ( in my query i use id for this)
You could exclude  the id related to  valud_id = 4 using a not IN

```
 select 
      manager_profile_id
      ,group_concat(value_id) as all_data
  from managers  
  where manager_profile_id =487 and team_id=2 
  and where id not in (  select distinct id from managers where value_id = 4 )
```